# Add button to catalog category in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add new button to category page on admin side with delete category and save category.I try the way to override the block `Catalog_Category_Edit_Form` but didn't work.My xml code is :

```
 <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
                <Catalog_Category_Edit_Form>Mymodule_Block_Rewrite_Editcate</Catalog_Category_Edit_Form>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
```

While my  block code is

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Block_Rewrite_Editcate extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form
{
    private $parent;

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
               // Delete button
         $this->parent = parent::_prepareLayout();

        $this->removeButton('delete_button');


        return $this->parent;
    }

}.
```

Can anyone help me the right way ? In above code i try to remove button to check my code works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys i find a solution .My new xml is look like

```
<adminhtml>

        <rewrite>
                <catalog_category_edit_form>Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form</catalog_category_edit_form>
            </rewrite>

            </adminhtml>
```

And my block code is :

```
<?php
class Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form
{

  protected function  _prepareLayout()
    {
           parent::_prepareLayout();
           $this->addAdditionalButton('update_button',  array('name' => 'update_button','title'=>'Copy Category','type'=>"button",'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Copy Category') ));

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }



}.
```

This is it.Mian function is addAdditionButton.Only pass parameter to it.I have override it.